# Yii2 : how to check value is unique with below scenario

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-validation

my table and its data

```
id   |type | email
1    |1    | user1@domain.com
2    |1    | user2@domain.com
3    |2    | user3@domain.com
4    |2    | user4@domain.com
5    |2    | user5@domain.com
```

Their is lots of type 1,2,3,4,5,..

All **TYPE** has dublicate emails except **type 2**

but,I want to make column email unique only for **type 2**
using yii2 model validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator#$filter-detail) and try something like this, not tested though

```
['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => Model::className(), 'filter' => function ($query) {
    return $query->andWhere(['type' => 2]);
}],
```